# How to connect Ubuntu to a MS SQL server 2005?

Tags: wine, database, sql, dotnet

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and I installed Wine 1.6. I am running a dotnet application through Wine, but I am getting the following error message:

> An error occurred while establishing connection to the server. When connecting to SQL server 2005,this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default setting SQL server does not allow remote connections.

The dotnet framework 2.0 installed in Ubuntu client. But the same dotnet applications runs in Windows client machines (Windows 7/Windows XP).

Do I need to establish connections manually to that server? Or do I need to install any application for this to establish connections?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Wine for this purpose. Connecting Ubuntu to a Microsoft SQL server is not really possible as the Microsoft MDAC doesn't install on Ubuntu, even in Wine. Here is a good guide that I found in this sense: http://www.omegaprojex.com/index.php/2010/10/15/connecting-ubuntu-to-sql-server-2005-natively/

Here is a quick overview:

1. Install all the packages needed to get connected to SQL server:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iodbc libiodbc2 libct3 tdsodbc unixodbc
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file and add the following:

   ```
   [FreeTDS]
   Description = FreeTDS Driver
   Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
   Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
   FileUsage = 1
   CPTimeout = 5
   CPReuse = 5
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/odbc.ini` file and add the following:

   ```
   [ODBC Data Sources]
   MyServerDSN = FreeTDS Connection Server
   [MyServerDSN]
   Driver = FreeTDS
   Description = FreeTDS Connection Server
   Servername = MyServer
   Database = MyDatabase
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/odbc.ini` file and add the following at the end of file:

   ```
   [MyServer]
   host = x.x.x.x
   port = 1433
   tds version = 8.5
   ```
5. Connect to SQL server:

   ```
   isql -v MyServerDSN MyUserName MyPass
   ```

Comment: it shows the following error message when i tried this command  :$ administrator@SRMCUBUNTU:~$ sudo apt-get install iodbc libiodbc2 libct3 tdsodbc unixodbc
[sudo] password for administrator: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libct3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  freetds-common

E: Package 'libct3' has no installation candidate

Comment: and also after entering this command : administrator@SRMCUBUNTU:~$ /etc/odbcinst.ini
bash: /etc/odbcinst.ini: Permission denied   what shall i do please help me

Comment: @jagadeesh To edit those files use for example: `sudo gedit /etc/odbcinst.ini`. You will never edit a file from terminal only inserting its name.

Comment: @jagadeesh At the first step you can try only with: `sudo apt-get install iodbc libiodbc2 tdsodbc unixodbc`

Comment: i did everything but still it is not working . myserver should be my server name ?  and wat abt host ? please help ....and in windows i dont need to assign ip address username password nothing ......